# Adding an image in email headers PHP

Tags: php, email

I want to add an image in the mail headers just like Youtube has when I receive an email from them. I'm simply using the php mail function to send emails, but I can't figure out how to implement this. Am I thinking it wrong?

[Here is the final result I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5fW5.png)

Thanks for your time,

Felix

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you actually ask. It is unclear what that image you linked actually shows, so it is useless.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass HTML as body in your email. 

The only problem is that outlook does not support it.
But all you have to do is build your email body in html and send it using PHP.
For the header it looks more like an tag or something, maybe it's not send via PHP. you could check out software like [mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com/).

P.S. make sure your image is hosting somewhere because you can't access it localy.